# How to fetch POST request body in XML format as a dictionary in Flask hit through Postman?

Tags: python, xml, api, flask, xmltodict

I am new to Flask. How can I fetch POST request body sent in XML format (mimetype="application/xml") through Postman as a dictionary in Flask API?

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <root>
                <name>Sam</name>
                <age>22</age>
            </root>'
```

Is there any method to do so, like we do in case of JSON using:

```
content = flask.request.get_json()
```

Or is it like that we can only send the POST request body in JSON format?

I have tried xmltodict but I am not able to fetch the XML in Flask through flask.request

```
content = xmltodict.parse(request.{what??})
```

Any resources regarding the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XML, if you send the XML as the value of a key in your POST request, e.g. POST Data is: xmldata="YOUR XML"

Read for more reference here: [Flask Api to parse xml post requests returning errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901197/flask-api-to-parse-xml-post-requests-returning-errors)

Comment: I need to parse the XML body which I will get in mimetype='application/xml'. Is there any workaround for this?